# How to echo woocommerce category name

Tags: wp-query, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy

Tried at least 5 SO answers, but nothing is working for me. I have this code and I want to output all the products within the category together with the category name on top:

```
<?php $params = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
        'tax_query'             => array(
            array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'slug', //This is optional, as it defaults to 'term_id'
                    'terms'         => array('bronchoscopes'),
                    'operator'      => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
            ),
    )

);
$products = new WP_Query($params);

?>
<?php if ($products->have_posts()) : // (3) ?>
<?php while ($products->have_posts()) : // (4)
                $products->the_post(); // (4.1) ?>
<?php the_title(); // (4.2) ?>
<?php echo single_term_title(); ?>
<?php echo the_category(); ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // (5) ?>
<?php else:  ?>
<p>
     <?php _e( 'No Products' ); // (6) ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I'm getting only my two products on the page, not the category name itself. What's the deal?

Answer (score 1):

You create `WP_Query` with `tax_query` and retrieve posts with category slug `bronchoscopes`. If you hardcoded category slug - you can hardcode also category name. Use [get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) inside loop and you will retrieve all categories attached to post. Or [get_the_term_list()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/).

Comment: `Missing argument 1 for get_the_term_list()` both are giving me the same error

Comment: Oh, my bad I forgot one argument. But it's not printing the category name anyways, only the products